# php - counting number of values in an array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I currently trying to do a count of how many properties are within a particular price range and the query I am running returns only a value of 1.  Obviously I am doing something wrong - and it doesn't help being not so MySQL/PhP savvy..
would anyone mind lending a hand please?

Query is below:

```
    $apart = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT m1.post_id
    FROM hj_postmeta m1
    INNER JOIN hj_postmeta m2 ON m1.post_id = m2.post_id
    WHERE m1.meta_key = 'price'
    AND m1.meta_value
    BETWEEN 50000 AND 74999 AND m2.meta_key = 'property_type'
    AND m2.meta_value = 'apartment'");

$apartprice = count($apart);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: let the DB do the counting `SELECT count(m1.post_id) as count ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `get_results` as `get_var` [*function returns a single variable from the database*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb):

```
$apart = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT m1.post_id
    FROM hj_postmeta m1
    INNER JOIN hj_postmeta m2 ON m1.post_id = m2.post_id
    WHERE m1.meta_key = 'price'
    AND m1.meta_value
    BETWEEN 50000 AND 74999 AND m2.meta_key = 'property_type'
    AND m2.meta_value = 'apartment'");

$apartprice = count($apart);
```

or COUNT all with `get_var`:

```
$apart = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(m1.post_id)
    FROM hj_postmeta m1
    INNER JOIN hj_postmeta m2 ON m1.post_id = m2.post_id
    WHERE m1.meta_key = 'price'
    AND m1.meta_value
    BETWEEN 50000 AND 74999 AND m2.meta_key = 'property_type'
    AND m2.meta_value = 'apartment'");

$apartprice = $apart;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, +1 for a fantastic answer!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are straight forward interested in the number of rows:

```
$apart = $wpdb->get_var("....");
$apartprice = $wpdb->num_rows;
```

However I think [Mihai Iorga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12555563/367456) raises two very fair points in case you need to fetch all the data or the (as commented above by  juergen d as well) count in the database if you do not actually process the resultset next to that one variable.